# Хостинги для публикации кода

Tags: хостинг, контроль-версий

Есть два понятия:

- **сниппет** — кусок кода, который можно использовать повторно,
- **система контроля версий** — система, используемая для того, чтобы несколько программистов работали над одним проектом и использовали один репозиторий.

Вопрос в следующем. Я пробовал пользоваться Github, но это несколько затратно ввиду моих нужд. Нужно, чтобы на некоем сайте можно было начать проект, была примитивная возможность создавать папки, сливать туда файлы с кодом, и этот же код, просматривать онлайн. Сливать именно через браузер, а не через систему контроля версий (часто работаю на разных компьютерах, а устанавливать и настраивать git, желания нет).

Сниппеты не катят, потому что это не файлы. А искать, если проект состоит более чем из одного файлы радости не доставляет. Плюс бывают файлы с моделями, а их таким образом уже не зальешь.

Заранее спасибо за дельные советы и ссылки.

Comment: Лично я не пробовал, но мне кажется, что это можно организовать на docs.google.com

Comment: Нет, файлы с расширением .py уже не открываются, а в другом формате хранить - это уже накладно. Пока лучшим вариантом остается dropbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в таких ситуациях (когда система контроля версий - слишком тяжеловесно) используют [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).

**UPD**

Несколько извращенный вариант, но просмотр кода он-лайн есть, да еще и с примочками: [CodeRemarks](http://www.coderemarks.com/)

Comment: Если бы в нем можно было просматривать код онлайн, вопроса бы не возникло, но возможно есть что-то похожее)))

Comment: Такие варианты я знаю, но моей наглой личности хочется чтобы все было, как на гитхаб только без гит, то есть открыл папку, кликнул на файл, он развернулся для просмотра.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вам просто подойдет онлайн-хранилище файлов как dropbox,или нужно что-то более специфичное?

Comment: Если бы в нем можно было просматривать код онлайн, вопроса бы не возникло, но возможно есть что-то похожее)))

Answer (score 1):

[OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/get-started/) похоже то, что требуется. Можно поставить свой сервер, можно купить хостинг с этим сервисом.

**Добавлено**.

Если все-таки выбирать из всех возможных вариантов, в том числе и с контролем версий, то можно начать отсюда: [сравнение хостингов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_hosting_facilities)

Comment: Штука хорошая, но все равно, все слишком усложняется, я так понял тут опять же своя прога, плюс, серва у меня нет, а за бабки, можно и на гитахабе с администрацией договорится. Но вообще, ресурс интересный.

Comment: Там есть демо сайт. http://demo.owncloud.org/files/index.php вполне самостоятельно без проги работает.

Comment: добавил ссылку на википедию, в которой есть сравнение хостингов для исходников...

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится система контроля версий Bazaar. Код сливаю на launchpad, где можно посмотреть код онлайн. Система является распределенной, что является удобной, когда пишу код на разных компьютерах, в разных операционных системах.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar